# In a mixture of Gaussions, why is the mixing coefficient greater than 0？

Tags: mixture-model

Also, the requirement that p(x) > 0, together with N(x|µk,Σk) > 0, implies πk > 0 for all k.

I can't understand the meaning of the sentence. Why is the mixing coefficient greater than 0? Can I think that each component of a mixture always provides positive effects for a mixture model?